# zIndex and display Properties not Behaving

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I'm relatively new to CSS, but have been making great progress.  I'm at a loss for this though, and can't seem to find the answer when searching.  My small site works as expected on Chrome, but not in IE.  I have a div in which I'm setting the zIndex to -1 to make it disappear.  When a button is clicked, I'm setting it to 100 to pop it back to the front.  In Chrome, this works like a charm.  In IE, instead of showing the div, it blanks the page and just shows "100" at the top of the page.  If I try to use display instead of zIndex, IE just prints whatever I set the display value to and wipes the page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body style="height:99%; width:99.8%;" onLoad="init();">
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: -50; left: -50" />
        <div id="topbuttons" style="visibility: hidden;">
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('optionspanel').style.zIndex=100" class="bluebuttons" id="btnShowOptions">Show Options</a>
        </div>
        <div id="map-canvas" style="float:left; width: 75%; height: 95%;"></div>
        <div id="optionspanel" style="position:absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; box-shadow: 5px 5px gray">
            panel stuff
        </div>
        <div id="rightpanel" style="float:right; width: 25%;">
            <div id="sidecelltop"></div>
            <div id="sidecell" style="text-align: center">
                <select id="radiuslist" name="radiuslist" multiple style="visibility: hidden"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

When a button is clicked, the zIndex of optionspanel is set to -1 and a Google map is displayed, along with showing the options button at the top of the screen.  When the options button is clicked, it is just supposed to set the zIndex of optionspanel to 100.  But in IE, it shows "100" at the top of the window and everything else goes away. =(

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

CS

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle that shows it actually happening? Sidenote: you seem to have a redundant `</table>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the z-index to -1. It's better to set that element to display: none. Also, you had a lot of crazy stuff happening in your code. I cleaned it up a bit. IE should like this better without all the extra syntax you had. This should be a better starting point to get the functionality you want.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Page</title>
        <style>
            body{
                width: 100%;
            }
            #files{
                visibility: hidden; 
                position: absolute; 
                top: -50; 
                left: -50;
            }
            #radiuslist{
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            #optionspanel{
                position:absolute; 
                top: 50px; 
                left: 50px; 
                background-color: white; 
                border: 1px solid black; 
                box-shadow: 5px 5px gray;
                display: none;
            }
            #map-canvas{
                float:left; 
                width: 75%; 
                height: 95%;
            }
            #rightpanel{
                float:right; 
                width: 25%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]"/>
        <div id="topbuttons">
            <span id="showOptions" class="bluebuttons">Show Options</span>
        </div>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        <div id="optionspanel">
            panel stuff
        </div>
        <div id="rightpanel">
            <div id="sidecelltop"></div>
            <div id="sidecell" style="text-align: center">
                <select id="radiuslist" name="radiuslist" multiple></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var show = document.getElementById('showOptions');
        show.onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('optionspanel').style.display = 'block';
        };
    </script>
</html>
```